# Draw DOM "pseudo" lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I am creating a little "diff -/ offset" display and I would like to draw somekind of a "line" to certain places within the text, to visualize where a "diff" occured. Basically I want to get from this:

[image]

to this or something similar:

[image]

I know about the canvas element and I can draw lines with that, but how could I place such an image in the correct place?

Is there maybe a "easy" CSS solution for an approach like this one ?

Are there any best practices I can follow? For instance, any ToolTip plugin/script must use something similar to point to a certain place.

I'm thankful for any helping hint on this. The original link to my jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/bKng6/

Comment: I am not sure it's what you want, but I have this function working with pure JS and DOM: http://jsfiddle.net/JjarF/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the expected behavior your application should do ( talking about the interaction with your end user ). you didn't mentioned how cross-browser the solution would be. Any way, I don't think pure CSS (also CSS3) would solve it without some JavaScript snippets. So, I would like to complement [tucuxi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532558/draw-dom-pseudo-lines/12318871#12318871) and [FelipeAls's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532558/draw-dom-pseudo-lines/12325531#12325531) sugestions.

Basically, about the line, some things to keep in mind during its development:

- theres a lot of solutions to draw the line. As mentioned Canvas its can be a choice, but I'm sure it isn't the simplier one.
- the working example suggested by [tucuxi](http://jsfiddle.net/eJQdx/2/) was done through CSS annitations, what is a good choice, simplier than canvas, and can be improved to accomplish the same design proposed by [FelipeAls's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532558/draw-dom-pseudo-lines/12325531#12325531).
- If your expected visual interaction with the end user is near to FelipeAls's suggestion a div with a 2px border width by default, plus both right and botton border width set to 0 will solve your line doubt. I've made working sample [right here](http://jsfiddle.net/miere/UxNhP/). On the proposed sample I've use DOM relative position to measure the correct line position. Although I did it using jQuery, you always will be able to do this in pure JS or another DOM based library as Mootools.

I really hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Where you want your marker, wrap the right side of the line in a span. Use border-bottom and border-left property.

Answer (score 1):

You can basically draw whatever you want by appending spans to you container
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/geCTY/2/)

select a color and draw by the mouse like you do on Paint.

Answer (score 1):

By combining:

- absolute positioning for comments (placed in the HTML code close to the text being added or removed so it's placed relative to it)
- "arrows" made of 2 borders on pseudo `:after`
- a visual cue that text is added or removed with pseudo `:before` and generated content '-' in CSS
- *visually hidden* text for screen reader users that won't know what is *added* or *removed* because information is mainly conveyed by the use of color and generated content in CSS (only VoiceOver will read that, and I'm not even sure in this case because screen readers tend to ignore single characters 'cause they've too often been abused as bullet points for making lists in plain text where HTML list items should've been used)

it's possible to have a result in pure HTML/CSS. It'll break fairly easily (if there is a word added on each line, comments on the right will be on top one of each other...) but with JS and `:hover` events (plus `:focus` and `tabindex` for sighted keyboard users, not forgetting touch events!) it's possible to avoid that.
Still it supports zoom text up to 200% (6th level of "zoom text only" in Firefox ); the problem is rather with the number of modifications and how close they're in text, the length of comments on right and absolute positioning.

==> **[DEMO in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/bKng6/5/)**

---

[image: snapshot of diff styled in pure HTML/CSS]

---

Answer (score 0):

I think you should better go with a tooltip. All the ways I can think of doing that with CSS seem hackish to me.

Take a look at this one for example: http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.html

I correct myself: Maybe you can get what you want using creating a element using ::before. I am not sure if that's the better option, depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can find offsets and dimensions via JavaScript, using jQuery's [offset](http://api.jquery.com/category/offset/)() and [width()/height()](http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/) calls. Once you have the boxes for source and destination, it is a matter of drawing lines between them. This you can do using plain HTML+CSS, by creating very thin, colored divs and rotating them as needed (if you use orthogonal lines, as you are do in your picture, no rotation is needed).

Given a jQuery element `e`, you can get its bounding box (left, top, width and height) using:

```
function box(e) {
    var b = e.offset();
    b.width = e.width();
    b.height = e.height();
    return b;
}
```

See this [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/eJQdx/2/), based on your original fiddle and @Mageek's comment.